# Set up an SFU server for a WebRTC application

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a WebRTC peer-to-peer application that sends video streams through peer connections and messages via data channels. The application is using the Mesh topology i.e. if there are N users in the room, each user has N-1 uplinks and N-1 downlinks.

I want to set up an SFU (Selective Forwarding Unit) to reduce the number of uplinks.

How should I proceed to shift from a Mesh to an SFU?

Answer (score 1):

Use an SFU like [mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org) or janus gateway

Comment: I read about these but not sure how to move my existing implementation to use these.

Comment: You can't move it. you need to rewrite it. It's completely different. There is no plug and play solution